# recommandation on modeling database in pocketbase

Tags: database-design, nosql, pocketbase

I am try to build a simple Todo application using Pocketbase where each user can Create/Read/Update/Delete todos that is private the user.I needed recommendation around the correct way to design the use case.
Initially i though of adding fields a list todo field inside the users collection.What should the type the of todos field? Should it be a select or a relation? I have created another `todos` collection with fields user, description. Now should the user by of type relation ? I have exposure to relational database and often think in terms of relations and foreign key. Since pocketbase db is NoSQL database, shouldn't  I  be allowed to nest the todo collection inside my user collection? Should todos be a root collection?

Even if you are familiar with pocketbase, any recommendation on how you would mode such situation in Nosql databases like mongodb,firebase db would help.I am frontend developer and my db skills and not that great. Any suggestion would be help me learn.

Answer (score 0):

pocketbase uses Sqlite under the hood, so it is no NoSQL database ;)

Nevertheless, I think your idea is right. You should have a todo table with a relation to the owning user and the rest of the columns save toto related data like description, content, priority,...
I would not recommend the nesting of data because it makes finding things in the db harder and slower on long term. NoSQL dbs hashes documents differently so they are still well performing while nesting entries. This is not the case in pocketbase.

No, you shouldn't nest todos into the user.

Yes, in my opinion todos is a root collection with relation to user (here the relation is named "user").

Get a todo with its user (js frontend):

```
const record = await pb.collection('todos').getOne('RECORD_ID', {
    expand: 'user',
});
```

Or get a User and use getList to get the first 50 todos of the user with:

```
const record = await pb.collection('users').getOne('RECORD_ID')

const resultList = await pb.collection('todos').getList(1, 50, {
    filter: 'user = "' + record.id + '"',
});
```

Hope, that helps you :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What do you mean with "pocketbase uses Sqlite under the hood, so it is no NoSQL database ;)"!? 

Sqlite is a relational database.